# Batch file to read the root directory it is in

Tags: batch-file

Is there a batch command that can read a root directory without the entire path?

I want a batch file to tell me if its in `D:\` or `E:\`.

I tried to use:

```
set mypath=%cd%
@echo %mypath%
Pause
```

But it just says the exact place it is in rather than just the root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few options for you which provide the root directory of the scripts current directory:

Using `PushD`/`Popd`

```bat
PushD\&Call Set "RootDir=%%CD%%"&PopD
Echo(%RootDir%
Pause
```

Using a `For` loop

```bat
For %%A In (%CD%) Do Set "RootDir=%%~dA\"
Echo(%RootDir%
Pause
```

Using variable expansion

```bat
Set "RootDir=%CD:~,3%"
Echo(%RootDir%
Pause
```

**Edit**

After reading your question again, I decided to add a fourth example. This one unlike the other three provides the root directory of the batch files location.

```bat
Set "RootDir=%~d0\"
Echo(%RootDir%
Pause
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the directory where the batch file is located could be different from the current directory cmd.exe operates in.

TO get the batch file root path use:

```
for %%a in ("%0") do echo %%~da
```

To ger the current directory use

```
echo "%cd:~0,3%"
```

Answer (score 2):

And let us not forget the &REM trick.

```
@ECHO OFF
set "root=%cd:\="&rem %
echo %root%
```

Comment: I like this one! **`:)`**